# Converting where clause of sql query to an equivalent filter program

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, expression-trees, boolean-expression, tree-traversal

**Problem description**

For a MYSQL query like :

```
 SELECT * from <<table>> where (a=1 and b<4) and c is between 1 and 4
```

I need to develop a where clause filter in JAVA, such that the job of where clause filter is done programmatically rather than using DB;

```
(a=1 or b<4) and c is between 1 and 4
```

The problem consists of two kinds of operations :

1. inequality operators, operand and values
2. Conjuncts (AND,OR,Between)

Following is my approach :

1. Make individual infix notations to prefix form :  **inequality_operator(operand,value).**

   ```
   =(a,1)
   >(b,4)
   between(c,(1,4))
   ```
2. Connect the parenthesized inequalities with conjuncts. Curly braces being indicators of conjunct operations.

   ```
   AND {=(a,1),>(b,4)}
   between(c,(1,4))
   ```

and eventually the ultimate connection after parenthesis prioritization.

```
 AND{AND {=(a,1),>(b,4)} , between(c,(1,4)) }
```

**Question** :

For parenthesis prioritization based inequality grouping , I need help so as which data structure(s) to use to accomplish this purpose so as to design nodes appropriately for the expression tree.

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement an expression parser. The [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is easy to understand and not complicated to implement. The standard algorithm generates postfix notation, and it looks like you want prefix notation, but that conversion isn't difficult at all.

Comment: @JimMischel : The algorithm you showed is making use of stack for parenthesis grouping. I need to use two stacks right? One for inequality expression + parenthesis based grouping, and, other for conjuncts curly brace grouping.. as in my case there are two level of operands as described in problem statement.

Comment: Why does it need to use string parsing? Wouldn't a code-based solution make more sense? Something like `And(And(Equals(Variable("a"), Constant(1), Greater(Variable("b"), Constant(4)), Between(Variable("c"), Constant(1), Constant(4)))`. It's more verbose, but it should also be much easier to manipulate.

Comment: Or maybe you could use lambdas: `x -> (x.a == 1 || x.b < 4) && x.c >= 1 && x.c <= 4 `.

Comment: Your conjuncts are just operators with slightly different syntax. You can easily convert them to a common intermediate syntax. For example, your expression in postfix is `a 1 = b 4 < OR c 1 4 BETWEEN AND`. That's easily converted to a something like `And(Or(Equals(a, 1), Greater(b,4)),Between(c,1,4))`

Comment: It needs to be stringd initially, then only using program i would be able to process the tree using function calls. Regarding other approach, i need to see how to do it in Java 7 @svick